# How do I add multiple reCAPTCHA in login and register page both are in single page in recat

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have login and register page in single page side by side .I wanted to add two reCAPTCHA in single page but when I added second captcha it throws me an error ": reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element"
can you please help me out

thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of having two in one page? If you have multiple forms why not apply one **reCAPTCHA** to the first form being submitted. If the results are true then why the need for having more? reCAPTCHA is a test to ensure that client is human and not a bot so passing the first test completes the purpose of using it.

Comment: I have two components in single page left side login page and register page so 
Can I add two reCAPTCHA in single page ?

Comment: The client is only going to do one of the choices... register ot login so i still see no reason for having two.